# Adding Migration Package to CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to add migration package to CakePHP 3.3 using the command

```
composer require cakephp/migration:~1.0
```

but I'm receiving the following result:

```
    ./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package cakephp/migration could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: It's "migration**s**" **https://github.com/cakephp/migrations#installation**

Answer (score 0):

As @ndm said its "migrations", also it should be allready installed by default if you created your app with composer or such. To activate it you just need to load it in the bootstrap.php as specified [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html)
 **Plugin::load('Migrations');**